# What to consider when creating new .java file in a package in eclipse that is supposed to depend on different imports

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, package

I am new to java and eclipse, so please excuse the simple question:

I am currently attempting to complete a project assignment in eclipse. So I have a project file under file explorer that has about 4 packages within it. Now, these all seem to be linked to a library that we are supposed to make use of, let's call it `data-science-lib` (fictitious name).

Now when I create a new .java file in a particular package, and write a few lines of code that are based on `data-science-lib` I am immediately asked to import many files because otherwise the code is not recognized. For all the other .java files in the package, there is no need to import because it seems as though it is already 'connected'. Moreover, my new .java file has a red cross symbol on it, rather than the blue M on the other current files. I am sure Maven has something to do with this but I am not sure how to solve it.

Question 1: What am I supposed to do when creating a new file such that my new .java file automatically identifies with the same 'dictionary' `data-science-lib` that all other current files identify with and would the red cross icon then perhaps turn into a blue M?

Question 2: I have cloned a repository that I would like to use and put it under projects in eclipse. It gets updated weekly online, but unfortunately the updated version only reflects online on github and not on my local eclipse. When I attempt to right-click and go to refresh, nothing happens. Any ideas?

Below you will find what the file icon looks like for the new .java file and the associated red cross and question mark.

[image: This is what the file icon looks like]

Comment: With the red cross you probably mean an error, right? Hover it or look into the _Problems_ view to get the error message. To get the changes from a cloned Git repository, you have to do a pull (in Eclipse, right-click the project and choose _Team > Pull_).

Comment: @howlger With the red cross I mean that that the red cross is placed on (in front of the) of the java file icon. For all the other files in the project, their file icon has no red cross but rather just a yellow/orange cylinder in front of it

Comment: That red cross indicates that there is one or more errors in the file. Open the file and in the editor hover the error marker or look in the _Problems_ view for the error message. The yellow/orange cylinder means the file is under version control, e.g. in a Git repository. See _Help > Help Contents_ for more information.